# Change Reference Column in Email

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to adapt the code to use column "J" as the reference column but with little success. I am not sure what I am missing to have the code use column "J" instead of column "A". Everything works as expected, the code just still references column "A" to get the email address to send to.

```
Sub EmailItems()

'Creates emails, attaches items, and choice to send automatically or have them pop up for your 
review. Delete the "'" in front of .Send in order to send automatically

Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String
Dim att As Variant
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = [O6]
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = [O5]
        .Body = [O7] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [O9] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [O11] & vbNewLine & 
             vbNewLine & [O13] & vbNewLine & [O14] & vbNewLine & [O15] & vbNewLine & [O16]
        On Error Resume Next
            For Each att In Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
            Attach.Add [O2] & att & [O3]
        Next
        .Display
        On Error GoTo 0
        '.Send
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ```.To = Cells(i, 1).Value``` should be ```.To = Cells(i, 10).Value```

Comment: I've made this change without success as well. Now the code does not create any emails.

Comment: Are there email addresses in Column J? the only thing that line would change is where it is getting the recipients from.

Comment: There are. For testing purposes they all are my email address but the cells are populate from J2:J5

Comment: What is the active workbook and active sheet? ```lastrow``` has explicit references but ```.to``` does not. It is possible that it's looking at the wrong sheet/book.

Comment: The only workbook I have open is the one I am working in, and I have open the "Email" worksheet.

Comment: I'd make the reference explicit either way. Might solve the issue, if not then step through and see where in the code it's getting lost.

Comment: Adding the explicit reference worked. Thank you for the assistance, I never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
Sub EmailItems()

'Creates emails, attaches items, and choice to send automatically or have them pop up for your 
review. Delete the "'" in front of .Send in order to send automatically

Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String
Dim att As Variant
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = [O6]
        .To = Cells(i, 10).Value
        .Subject = [O5]
        .Body = [O7] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [O9] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [O11] & vbNewLine & 
             vbNewLine & [O13] & vbNewLine & [O14] & vbNewLine & [O15] & vbNewLine & [O16]
        On Error Resume Next
            For Each att In Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
            Attach.Add [O2] & att & [O3]
        Next
        .Display
        On Error GoTo 0
        '.Send
    End With

Next

End Sub
```